# Sumset of $(-\infty,0]$ and $[0,\infty).$

Tags: general-topology

For $X ,Y \subseteq \Bbb R$, define $X + Y = \{x + y : x \in X, y \in Y\}$. If $X = (-\infty,0]$  and  $Y = [0,\infty)$, find $X + Y.$

I think $X + Y = (-\infty, 0] + [0, \infty) \neq (-\infty,\infty)$ but $X \cup Y = (-\infty, 0] \cup [0 + \infty) = (-\infty,\infty)$
and $X$ and $Y$ are closed sets. I think $X + Y$ is closed but I have seen that the sum of two closed sets may not be closed. I would be surprised to see $X + Y = X \cup Y.$ Please help me.

Comment: What is $\{0\} + [0, \infty)$? What about $(-\infty, 0] + \{0\}$? Why must $X + Y$ contain both as subsets?

Comment: $\{0\} + [0, \infty) = [0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty, 0] + \{0\} = (-\infty, 0]$ Why there a negative vote?

Comment: I really don't know.

Answer (score 2):

$X+Y = \mathbb{R},$ since every positive real $y$ can be written as $0 + y$ and every negative real $x$ can be written as $x + 0,$ and zero can be written as $0+0.$

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second question: in general, it isn't true that $X+Y=X\cup Y$. Moreover, we can't even say that either $X+Y \subseteq X\cup Y$ or $X+Y \supseteq X \cup Y$ is true in general. Take for example $X=(0,1)$ and $Y=(2,3)$. Then, you can check that
$$
(0,1)+(2,3) = (2,4),
$$
hence you see that $(2,4) \neq (0,1) \cup (2,3)$ and that $(2,4) \not\subseteq (0,1)\cup(2,3)$ and $(2,4) \not\supseteq (0,1)\cup(2,3)$. Hope this helps!